# How to add two widgets in a tk.Frame located inside a tk.Canvas?

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, scrollbar, frame

I'm trying to do a scrollable application with two buttons. Pressing one of those buttons should be put a new button in the Frame, and scroll the widgets inside the frame.

**My question is how to put the two buttons in the frame?**

when I try to put in the same Frame only I can see one button and only a small part of the other.
How to solve this?

```
from tkinter import *   # from x import * is bad practice
global y
y=0
def _configure_interior(event):
    print("hola")
    size = (interior.winfo_reqwidth(), interior.winfo_reqheight())
    canvas.config(scrollregion="0 0 %s %s" % size)

def newbutton():
    buttons=Button(interior, text="Button ")
    buttons.pack()
    #b2.place(y=50)


root =Tk()
#configuring the Scrollbars
vscrollbar = Scrollbar(root, orient=VERTICAL)
vscrollbar.pack(fill=Y, side=RIGHT)
hscrollbar = Scrollbar(root, orient=HORIZONTAL)
hscrollbar.pack(fill=X, side=BOTTOM)

#setting canvas with scrollbar
canvas = Canvas(root,height=500, width=500, bg="blue",
            yscrollcommand=vscrollbar.set,xscrollcommand=hscrollbar.set)
canvas.propagate(0)
vscrollbar.config(command=canvas.yview)
hscrollbar.config(command=canvas.xview)
canvas.pack()

#making a interior scrolleable frame
interior = Frame(canvas,bg='black',height=600,width=600)
interior.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

#adding some widgets to the Frame
b=Button(interior, text="Button 2",command=newbutton)
b.pack()
b2=Button(interior, text="Button 2",command=newbutton)
b2.pack()
b2.place(x=50,y=50)

interior_id = canvas.create_window(30,30, window=interior,
                                 anchor=NW)
interior.bind('<Configure>', _configure_interior)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have also used `pack()` to place the `interior` frame on the canvas, which does not work. I've commentet that line out in the code below. Also I've commented out the `b2.place()` as you should not use more tham one geometry manager in a frame.

```
#making a interior scrolleable frame
interior = Frame(canvas,bg='black',height=600,width=600)
#interior.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
interior_id = canvas.create_window(30,30, window=interior,
                                 anchor=NW)

#adding some widgets to the Frame
b=Button(interior, text="Button 2",command=newbutton)
b.pack()
b2=Button(interior, text="Button 2",command=newbutton)
b2.pack()
#b2.place(x=50,y=50)
```

The new buttons are now packed into `interior`.